# How to use function from toolbox that I downloaded by myself in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I download a toolbox (ghsom) from website: [http://www.ofai.at/~elias.pampalk/ghsom/download.html](http://www.ofai.at/%7Eelias.pampalk/ghsom/download.html)

In the website, it shows:

> Download ghsom.zip (144KB) - Version 29.10.2002
>
> Extract and copy files into e.g. "c:\matlab\toolbox\ghsom" directory.
>
> Modify the path settings. This can be done in Matlab with e.g.
> "addpath c:\matlab\toolbox\ghsom". Notice that it is also possible
> to automatically add a toolbox path by adding the "addpath" command to
> the "startup.m" file in the "toolbox\local" directory. (If the file
> does not exist, it can be created by the user.)
>
> Try some demonstrations such as "ghsom_demo".

I have tried its instruction but shows similar problem below.

Besides, I tried several method to import this toolbox:

> 1 copy the file directly to the path: ...Polyspace\R2019b\toolbox
>
> 2 click the button "Add-Ons" in Home and add the package, then
> install mltbx file, then it shows there are prj file

However, I was still confused about how to use my toolbox, because there are many m file in this folder includes some demo file. Now I want to run those demo file,but it didn't work, and show:

```
Unable to resolve the name ghsom.som_read_data
```

How to solve this problem, I mean I just want to run the demos in this folder.

Comment: What about the method described in your linked webpage ?

Comment: @obchardon Hi, thanks for your reply, I add more detail on question. please check if you have time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence on the download page you linked says

> The GHSOM Toolbox requires the SOM Toolbox (Version 2) to be installed.

So, you need to install the SOM Toolbox, which probably contains the function `som_read_data` that you got an error message about.

The page referenced above has a link to the SOM Toolbox.